# Is it possible to let a two objects move with follow path?

Tags: animation

So, let me explain. I have two objects and a camera. I made the camera turn around my objects using the method in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76yCn3waki8) so by parenting the camera to a circle and making it "follow path".

Now I'd also love to make one of the objects turn around the other object, but when I try to apply the same method, the option follow path doesn't show up when pressing cmd P.

I've tried other ways of animating the second movement, like with keyframes, but the movement is never as smooth as "follow path".

Here's a screenshot of my screen, the "vrg" is supposed to flip around the logo behind it. [image]
[image] The second picture shows the curves: the big circle is for the camera, the smaller circle should be for the "vrg".

Does anyone have an explanation for why it doesn't work, a solution on how to fix it, or a suggestion of another way to easily make my second object turn?

https://we.tl/t-a1qmhnCRGA

Comment: Hello could you please share your file, and tell what object is supposed to turn around what object?

Comment: hi @moonboots ! i've added a screenshot! it's two mesh objects around each other

Comment: So you are trying to make another object follow the same curve? It's not clear, maybe share your file?

Comment: @moonboots The camera turns horizontally, along the circle that is still visible on the screenshot, and the vrg was supposed to turn vertically around the logo. I already deleted this last curve to try to fix it with keyframes, so maybe i can send you a screenvideo of what i have now with keyframes, but want to do with the 'follow path' function!

Comment: So you want to vrg follow the same curve? Follow Path only works with curves as Target.

Comment: @moonboots https://we.tl/t-a1qmhnCRGA, here you go! the video was too big so I put in in a wetransfer link! It's very obvious how the second movement is way less smooth than the first in the video

Comment: @moonboots no it's not the same curve! i'll redraw the second curve for vrg and add a screenshot for clarification.

Comment: I don't know why you can't make it follow this path, again please share your file, remove the useless elements

Comment: @moonboots https://we.tl/t-IT8UkPxPqC here is the link to my file. Thank you so much for helping me!!!!

Comment: If I select VRG, shift select one of your curve and press Ctrl P, I have Follow Path available, same thing with the other object, are you sure that you do it right? Also you can directly select the object and create a constraint > Follow Path

Comment: @moonboots oh, i see, i think i didn't select the curve while creating a constraint! Now it works! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Select the object, shift select the curve and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Follow Path*, it will create a *Follow Path* constraint in the *Object Constraint* panel. Or you can directly select the object, give it a *Follow Path* constraint and choose the curve you want as *Target*.